# В чем причина ошибки (Spring Vaadin)?

Tags: jpa, spring, java

Здраствуйте! Не знаю куда обратиться) Очень нужна помощь!

Ошибка:

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'monApplication': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Could not autowire field:
> kz.mon.servlet.controllers.MainComponent
> kz.mon.servlet.controllers.AtmserviceApplication.mainComponent;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'mainComponent' defined in file
> [/home/camaro/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ATMService/WEB-INF/classes/kz/mon/servlet/controllers/MainComponent.class]:
> Instantiation of bean failed; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Could not instantiate bean class
> [kz.mon.servlet.controllers.MainComponent]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested
> exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException 
> com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.handleServiceException(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:999)
> com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:548)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

---

Мой основной класс

AtmserviceApplication.class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;

@Component(value = "monApplication")
@Scope(value = "session")
public class AtmserviceApplication extends Application {

    @Autowired
    MainComponent mainComponent;

..........................................................
```

MainComponent.class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.vaadin.annotations.AutoGenerated;
import com.vaadin.data.Property;
import com.vaadin.data.Property.ValueChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Alignment;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.CheckBox;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalSplitPanel;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.ListSelect;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Table;
import com.vaadin.ui.Tree;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalSplitPanel;

@Component(value = "mainComponent")
@Scope(value = "session")
public class MainComponent extends CustomComponent {

(Ошибка когда пытаюсь подключить следующюю строчку)

    @Autowired
    SourceControllerInterface sourceController;

...............................................................................
```

SourceControllerImplementation.class

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.JPAContainer;

@Component(value = "sourceController")
@Scope(value = "session")
public class SourceControllerImplementation implements
        SourceControllerInterface {
    public SourceControllerImplementation() {
    }

    @Resource(name = "atmModelProvider")
    private AtmModelProvider atmProvider;

    public String getATMContainer() {
        JPAContainer<ATM> container = new JPAContainer(ATM.class);
        System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAA");
        container.setEntityProvider(atmProvider);
        System.out.println(container.size());
        return "ХЛАБЫСЬ!";
    }
}
```

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Could not instantiate bean class [kz.mon.servlet.controllers.MainComponent]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException 
NPE в конструкторе MainComponent - как выглядит конструктор этого класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем спасибо, причина нашлась, проблема была в том, что запрос был в конструкторе, т.е. класс еще не заварился, а уже был запрос, поэтому и нуллпоинтер, вынес из класса `MainComponent` из конструктора в отдельный метод и над ним поставил `@Postconstruct`, и все стало нормально.